# ¿Como utilizar esta API Climatológica?

Tags: c#, sql, json

Hola compañeros programadores, tengo una pregunta, primeramente estoy realizando un proyecto en el cual necesito la informacion de x ciudad sobre su clima, más que nada resultados numéricos, pero no se como hacerlo, me recomendaron esta pagina "https://smn.cna.gob.mx/es/web-service-api" pero no se como obtener los datos desde c#, alguna ayuda o que es lo que necesito para empezar a hacerlo?

Gracias de antemano

Comment: Bienvenido, favor de leer [ask], para poder esperar ayuda de la comunidad es necesario edites tu pregunta y coloques que llevas hecho o investigado

Comment: En el propio web service te indica como realizar la petición de datos y como sería la respuesta esperada. Como bien dice Alfa seria interesante que añadieses el código con lo que has intentado ya que sino es bastante probable que la pregunta termine cerrada.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

antes que cualquier otra cosa, procura que tus preguntas sean específicas respecto a problemas puntuales y trata de documentar bien el problema para que las respuestas puedan ser más concretas.

Lo que planteas es ¿Cómo consultar información de un WebService desde una aplicación escrita en C#?

El [sitio que mencionaste](https://smn.cna.gob.mx/es/web-service-api) parece tener una breve pero clara descripción sobre el modo de hacer un llamado, pero le hace falta mencionar un breve detalle.

La información entregada por ese WebService posee dos características destacables a tomar en cuenta dentro de la aplicación que vayas a realizar:

- El WebService regresa un JSON comprimido en GZip
- La información se actualiza cada 1 hora y 15 minutos

El llamado es general y siempre regresa resultados para todas las ciudades, aparentemente no posee argumentos con los cuales filtrar la información solicitada y el archivo resultante pesa aproximadamente 16 MB (al menos en la solicitud que yo hice)

La estructura del JSON está descrita en la página que mencionas, salvo por el detalle de los campos Latitud y Longitud, los cuales dicen ser de tipo `Int` pero en realidad son valores decimales, por lo cual el módelo debe acoplarse.

me tomé la libertad de crear un repositorio en el cual hice un programa de ejemplo en .NET Core para solicitar información desde ese servicio

https://github.com/erickisos/ClimatologiaMX

La explicación esencial es

### Llamar a un WebService desde .NET Core (C#)

Existen diversos modos pero el que he utilizado se basa en la clase `HttpClient` contenida dentro de [`System.Net.Http`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.7.2)
El ejemplo base de llamado es el siguiente (Tomado desde la documentación de Microsoft):

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    try    
    {
        var response = await client.GetStreamAsync("https://smn.cna.gob.mx/webservices/?method=1");
    }  
    catch(HttpRequestException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nException Caught!");    
        Console.WriteLine("Message :{0} ",e.Message);
    }
}
```

### Descomprimiendo una respuesta GZip

Dado que la respuesta del WS es un conjunto de datos comprimidos es necesario efectuar una descompresión antes de la deserialización, para ello tal como viene en la [documentación oficial](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/io/how-to-compress-and-extract-files) hacemos uso de `System.IO.Compression` agregando entonces el siguiente segmento de código.

```
using (var decompressionStream = new GZipStream(stream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
{
    ...
}
```

### Serializar un JSON a un Objeto de C

Para esto, utilizando la librería `System.Runtime.Serialization.Json` y dependiendo previamente de la creación de modelos que sirvan como template de la respuesta agregamos un segmento como el siguiente:

```
var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Respuesta));
...
var data = (Respuesta)serializer.ReadObject(stream);
```

asumiendo que la clase *Respuesta* tiene una estructura similar a la siguiente

```
[DataContract]
public class Respuesta
{
    [DataMember]
    public String Elemento { get; set; }
}
```

teniendo tantos elementos como el JSON a Deserializar/Serializar, puedes encontrar más información al respecto en [¿Cómo Serializar y Deserilaizar datos de un JSON?](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-serialize-and-deserialize-json-data)

### Ejemplo

Juntando todos los segmentos de código descrito y las referencias a las librerías, el programa seria esencialmente algo similar a esto

```
public async static void Main(string[] args)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        try
        {
            using (var response = await client.GetStreamAsync("https://smn.cna.gob.mx/webservices/?method=1"))
            using (var decompress = new GZipStream(response, CompressionMode.Decompress))
            {
                var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Respuesta));
                var data = (Respuesta)serializer.ReadObject(decompress);
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", data);
            }
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Excepción Capturada: {0}", e.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: En ese entonces apenas y empezaba a entender la programación, y no te agradecí en ese momento, pero derivado de tu ayuda pude lograr muchas cosas, gracias!

Comment: Muchas gracias por el comentario, ojalá le sea útil a otras personas.